# Why does my Snowbush have only purple leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, shrubs, tropical

My [Snowbush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breynia_disticha) had lovely pink, green and white leaves for several years. Now all I get is purple leaves.

Is this a magnesium or potassium problem? Or, who has a solution?

Comment: Hi! I added a link to the Wikipedia article for _Breynia disticha_. If that's not correct, please feel free to change it. Also, if you have a photograph of your plant, please add it because it might help us diagnose the problem. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Is this plant surrounded by other permanent planting? If so, has the other planting increased in size over the years, or a building has been put up, which means the Snowbush receives much more shade than it used to?

Comment: No, it is taller than anything near it.

Comment: I didn't find any link. I had already seen in online, but I didn't find anything that said anything about purple leaves. Actually, they are kind of medium green with purple edges. I put some bulb food on it that has magnesium and potassium in it, and I have to water it in. Maybe that will help.

Comment: If your plant is Breynia disticha, the usual cause for the leaves remaining purplish and not acquiring the variegated colouration is insufficient sunlight, and not a lack of nutrients. It may be its no longer getting the amount of sunlight it once did, so observation of it during a sunny day would be useful.